# How to remove select DOM completely while using select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

The **destroy** method only removes the select2's support DOM created by the plugin. But I can still see the basic *select* tag in the DOM tree. 
Currently I'm doing the following to get rid of the select I created using select2:

```
$("#elID").select2('destroy');
$("#elID").remove();
```

There must be some plugin support itself to achieve this properly. But I'm unable to find it anywhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$("#auditID").select2('destroy').remove();`

Answer (score 3):

After calling destroy of the plugin, remove the element using `remove()`;

```
$("#auditID").select2('destroy').remove();
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $("#auditID").select2('destroy').remove();
})
$("#auditID").select2();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select id="auditID">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<button>Remove</button>
```

Comment: Yeah, using chain-able feature is a nice idea. If there's support in plugin itself it would've been awesome

Comment: @Nachikethashu The plugin should destroy only those items it created.... since the select is not created by the plugin it should not destroy it

Comment: One more drawback of destroy is it throws error if there are no selects in dom. Not like usual jquery remove api.